# Run Windows command line in Task Scheduler without opening a cmd window

Tags: windows, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I set up a Windows task schedule to run every five minutes. The task starts the `cmd.exe` program and runs a command.

The problem is that every five minutes a `cmd` window is opened and it's annoying. Is there a way to handle this without opening the `cmd` window?

The command I run is:

```
/c for  %f in (*) do "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe"  /command "open ftp://user:pass@thost.com/"   "rm "%f" " "close" "exit"
```

Comment: See this>>>>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411247/running-a-cmd-or-bat-in-silent-mode

Comment: Also see this>>>>https://www.raymond.cc/blog/hidden-start-runs-batch-files-silently-without-flickering-console/

Answer (score 1):

To hide the cmd window, choose "Run whether user is logged on or not" when creating the task.

[image]